# Ethereum Wallet - Hangs at startup + 403 ws error

Tags: wallets, mist, synchronization, error, websocket

I have installed the Ethereum Wallet, Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-11-1 (zip file), as described in the book. When I start up Ethereum Wallet (testnet Ropsten, syncmode “light”) the wallet seems to load forever.

[image]

In the logfile main I find the following entries:

```
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.278] [INFO] Settings - Running in production mode: true
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.387] [INFO] main - Starting in Wallet mode
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.413] [INFO] Db - Loading db: C:\Users\nicob\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\mist.lokidb
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.432] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.433] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
[2020-10-22T15:54:23.519] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2020-10-22T15:54:26.594] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc"}
[2020-10-22T15:54:27.676] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2020-10-22T15:54:27.698] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2020-10-22T15:54:27.698] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
[2020-10-22T15:54:27.712] [INFO] main - Loading Interface at file://C:\Users\nicob\ethereum\Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-11-1 (1)\resources\app.asar/interface/wallet/index.html
[2020-10-22T15:54:27.796] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2020-10-22T15:54:28.797] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.141] [WARN] EthereumNodeRemote - Error from ws:  Error: Unexpected server response: 403
    at ClientRequest.req.on (C:\Users\nicob\ethereum\Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-11-1 (1)\resources\app.asar\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:542:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:565:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:589:20)
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.148] [WARN] EthereumNodeRemote - Remote WebSocket connection closed (code: 1006). Reopening connection...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.394] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.396] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.397] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.397] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.398] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.399] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.399] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.400] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.618] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.618] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2020-10-22T15:54:29.799] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2020-10-22T15:54:30.597] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Meteor starting up...
[2020-10-22T15:54:30.788] [ERROR] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed (3000ms elapsed)
[2020-10-22T15:54:32.420] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Meteor starting up...
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.894] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc"}
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.897] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.900] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"path":"\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc"}
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.901] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connect to {"path":"\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc"}
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.903] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2020-10-22T15:54:33.904] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connected!
```

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum Wallet you are using is the [Mist application](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases). The work on this application ended [on March 22, 2019](https://medium.com/@avsa/sunsetting-mist-da21c8e943d2).

The error you are seeing is probably due to the fact that the application has not been updated with the latest Ethereum changes.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a picture..but you can try ..NODE.js-.

And possibly attempt swiching networks in combination with .ipfs.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by trying Node.js, and how ipfs is relevant to the conversation?